# RSpec specs not running?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm having trouble running some rspec specs on a Sinatra app.  I'm just learning Ruby, so unfortunately I don't know enough to fix the problem I'm having with code from a book (Service Oriented Design in Ruby on Rails, by Paul Dix).

The problem is these tests aren't really running (I think).  From the app directory, I run `$ ruby spec/service_spec.rb`, and I get no indication of the tests passing or failing.  I get a couple of log messages from the file `/service.rb`, but that's all the output shown.  I put in some `puts` calls to show that the before blocks and it blocks aren't getting executed (even though the describe blocks are).

If you want to see more about the code, check out [the repository on Github](https://github.com/pauldix/service-oriented-design-with-ruby/tree/master/chapter_01).

**/spec/service_spec.rb:**

```
ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] = 'test'

require_relative '../service'
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'

RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

describe "service" do
  puts 'describe 1'
  before(:each) do
    puts 'before 1'
    User.delete_all
  end

  describe "GET on /api/v1/users/:id" do
    puts 'describe 2'
    before(:each) do
      puts 'before 2'
      User.create(
        :name => "paul",
        :email => "paul@pauldix.net",
        :password => "strongpass",
        :bio => "rubyist")
    end

    it "should return a user by name" do
      puts 'it 1'
      get '/api/v1/users/paul'
      last_response.should be_ok
      attributes = JSON.parse(last_response.body)["user"]
      attributes["name"].should == "paul"
    end

    it "should return a 404 for a user that doesn't exist" do
      puts 'it 2'
      get '/api/v1/users/foo'
      last_response.status.should == 404
    end
  end
end
```

**/service.rb:**

```
require 'active_record'
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'models/user'
require 'logger'

# log levels are DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < UNKNOWN
log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
log.level = Logger::DEBUG

# set up the environment
env_index = ARGV.index("-e")
env_arg = ARGV[env_index + 1] if env_index
env = env_arg || ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] || "development"
log.debug "env: #{env}"

# set up database connection
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
databases = YAML.load_file("config/database.yml")
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(databases[env])
log.debug "#{databases[env]['database']} database connection established"

# HTTP entry points
# get a user by id
get '/api/v1/users/:name' do
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    if user
        user.to_json
    else
        error 404, { error: "user not found" }.to_json
    end
end
```

**$ ruby spec/service_spec.rb output:**

```
D, [2013-03-16T17:05:58.275276 #17685] DEBUG -- : env: test
D, [2013-03-16T17:05:58.290885 #17685] DEBUG -- : db/test.sqlite3 database connection established
describe 1
describe 2
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `spec/spec_helper.rb`?  Did you run `rspec --init` at the top of your app tree?

Comment: If you've done that, try running `rspec spec/service_spec.rb` (or just `rspec` with no args) instead of `ruby spec/service_spec.rb`.  It looks like RSpec might not be bootstrapping properly.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that fixed the problem!  No, I did not have a spec_helper, so I ran rspec --init (which created the spec_helper file), and now it's working.  If you post an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per comments on question, this was fixed by running `rspec --init` to bootstrap RSpec with a `spec/spec_helper.rb` file.